# Cocoonjs soundjs not playing on ios

Tags: html5-audio, cocoonjs, soundjs

We're building an html project using cocoonjs webview+, but soundjs doesn't play when we open our app on ios.

Everything works fine on android in webview+, and we've tried mp3, ogg, and m4v sound files with ios. Does anyone have any idea what we could try next.

This is applying to both autoplay sounds, and sounds that are triggered by user interaction (e.g. in onclick handlers).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Cocoonjs is based on Cordova, so you should be able to use the new [CordovaAudioPlugin](http://www.reddit.com/r/createjs/comments/30azch/soundjs_cordovaaudioplugin/) with the lastest [SoundJS-Next](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS).

Previously there have been problems the default WebAudioPlugin because it requires XHR to load audio with is not available for local files.  People got around this by not using default plugins and instead registering HTMLAudioPlugin.

Also, iOS web sites requires audio to be played inside a user event, but I'm not sure if this same restriction is applied to webviews.  If it is, the [Mobile Safe Tutorial](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mobile%20Safe%20Approach/) might be useful.

Hope that helps.